# Installing Telerik and Devexpress on the Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, telerik, devexpress

I have a Visual Studio 2017 with Devexpress components installed. Would it be a problem if I will also install Telerik components?

Comment: May be not.. They are independent component providers and should not effect another product installation.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I installed them both. Seems there is no any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devexpress and Telerik can be used side-by-side in the same Visual Studio installation without any problems. I use them both frequently, and they do not seem to cause any conflicts with each other.